# Hyper-V Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise + Linux licenses

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, virtualization, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I know with Enteprise we get four Enterprise virtual licenses as well as the physical license. How many Linux guests could we run though? If we had four Enterprise virtual machines would we be able to run as many Linux virtual machines that hardware would allow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/5/8/F58E786D-529D-438A-8625-4948205D8BA5/Windows_Hyper_V_Licensing_Whitepaper_v2_0.docx):

"*Is there a limit on how many guests I can run when I license Windows Server Enterprise? What if I run all Linux guests?*

The Windows Server Enterprise license includes up to 4 guests; additional licenses are required if you have more than four Windows Server guests. If you are running Linux, you need to determine the licensing requirements for Linux from your Linux vendor. Microsoft does not place limitations on the number of Linux-based guests a hosting provider may run."

-Josh

Comment: Thanks. Saw this before and it seemed vague to me--does this mean yes? To me it does but I've got to convince other people. Right now they're telling me I can only run four of any combination of Linux and Windows.

Comment: Well I looked at it again and it seems clear to me. Thanks again.

Comment: The license allows 5 instances of your enterprise copy - 1xHardware Installed and 4xVM Installed. There is no limit on the amount of virtual machines that you can run and is only bound to the EULA's of the vendor for the OS that you have installed.